# kernel change MMAP memory but user space not change

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, mmap

1. Goal: I want to transfer data from kernel driver to user space app real time.
2. Method: I use mmap to connect kernel buffer_K and user buffer_U. When I change write data to K, the U will be changed also.
3. Problem: When I changed the buffer_K, use mmcpy(buffer_k, buffer_another, length), the buffer_K changed, but the buffer_U not change, my change frequency is 4ms.

This is my code
In kernel space, if kernel work done, it will trigger a signal to notice user space.

```
static uint8_t *mmap_buffer;
mmap_buffer = (uint8_t *)kmalloc(ads1299.samp_size * ads1299.buff_size, GFP_KERNEL);

int event()
{
    memcpy(mmap_buffer, ads1299.buff_a, ads1299.buff_size * ads1299.samp_size);
    SEND_SIGNAL_TO_APP;
}

int ads1299_mmap(struct file *flip, struct vm_area_struct *vma)
{
    unsigned long page;
    unsigned long start = (unsigned long)vma->vm_start;
    unsigned long size = (unsigned long)(vma->vm_end - vma->vm_start);
    vma->vm_flags |= VM_IO;
    vma->vm_flags |= VM_SHARED;
    page = virt_to_phys(mmap_buffer);

    if(remap_pfn_range(vma,start,page>>PAGE_SHIFT, size, vma->vm_page_prot))
    {
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is my user code

```
unsigned char *buffer= NULL;
buffer = (unsigned char*)malloc(charDataLen*sizeof(unsigned char));
buffer = (unsigned char *)mmap(NULL, getpagesize(), PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);

if(buffer == MAP_FAILED)
{
    printf("mmap error\r\n");
    return -1;
}

int signal_handle()
{
    usebufer(buffer)
}
```

Could you tell me some suggestion about my problem. Thanks.

Comment: `malloc` before `mmap` doesn't make any sense, as you allocate some unrelated memory and then leak it when you overwrite the pointer.  Probably not your issue, but maybe suggests other problems.

Comment: I find it is the buffer size problem, if I use 1-page size(in my machine it is 4096bytes) buffer, I can make it work.